Rebooting directly into MOK
I'd like to enroll a new key in a GCP VM. I'm using the mok --import command, and rebooting form the serial console. The problem is that, when the splash screen appears, the serial console does not accept any input, and I can't get passed the 30 second splash screen.
Is there any other way to force the enrollment of a new key or starting mok manager while the machine is booted? ( for the second I'm quite sure not:) ).
Thank you
